# How to display an html content after a javascript progress bar has finished loading

Tags: javascript, html

I make a javascript progress bar that is suppose to display some result after the progress bar has finish loading. but i don't know how to display content after the progress bar has finish loading.. here is my code for the progress bar so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 

<script>
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

my question now is how can make some element to display after the progress bar has finish loading, like getting to 100%. the element should be hidden while the page loads, and it should be displayed when the progress bar gets to 100%.

thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css style to hide your content on page load and when your progress bar is completed you can change its display property .Check the working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
#content{
    display:none;
}

</style>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>


<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 
<div id="content">Hello</div>

<script>
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      document.getElementById('content').style.display='block';
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display property from hidden to block or inline-block, depending in what layout are you looking for. Just add the code inside your if statement when the progress bar reaches 100.

```
document.getElementByID(“youhiddenElementId”).style.display = ‘block’;
```